# How to get the 'expected' type of a CoreData attribute in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

I am writing an app in iOS SDK 8.4 in Xcode Version 6.4 (6E35b) using Swift. I have a .xcdatamodeld file that has an entity named 'Assessment'. The 'Assessment' entity has several attributes of types: String, Bool, and Float. When I check via the `attributeType` accessor in NSAttributeDescription as suggested in many posts, I receive a nil value which makes sense, because I'm using an instance which has not mapped all values to the attributes.

From apple's reference:
"The NSAttributeDescription class is used to describe attributes of an entity described by an instance of NSEntityDescription."

How do I get the type of an attribute as I defined in the .xcdatamodeld file programmatically?

Comment: You do it... using `NSAttributeDescription`. A nil value actually doesn't make sense in the situation you describe. You should edit your question to include code that shows how you're trying to do this, because as you describe it you're doing the right thing but somehow getting the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

Know this is old but wanted to update it with an answer of how I am doing it in Swift 4:

```
let attributeDescription = myDataSource.entity.attributesByName

    for thisDescription in attributeDescription {
        if thisDescription.1.attributeType == .integer16AttributeType {
            print(thisDescription.0)
        }
    }
```

Where myDataSource is a NSManagedObject I fetched from Core Data. In my example I was looking to make a grid with the max col being the highest int value of my managed object. attributeDescription is a tuple, 0 provides the string title you gave to an attribute, 1 is a dictionary of values of the attribute.

You can view all the attributeTypes here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsattributetype